# how to combine different categorical attribute values in dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am working on NYC property sales dataset(https://www.kaggle.com/new-york-city/nyc-property-sales).

There is one column "BUILDING CLASS CATEGORY", which has several different categorical string values. What I want to do is to choose only the top 4 categories which have maximum occurrences and combine the rest of the values into a single one.
For ex-

```
> dataset["BUILDING CLASS CATEGORY"].value_counts()

01 ONE FAMILY DWELLINGS                         12686
10 COOPS - ELEVATOR APARTMENTS                  11518
02 TWO FAMILY DWELLINGS                          9844
13 CONDOS - ELEVATOR APARTMENTS                  7965
09 COOPS - WALKUP APARTMENTS                     2504
03 THREE FAMILY DWELLINGS                        2318
07 RENTALS - WALKUP APARTMENTS                   1743
```

so what I want is that all the instances of top 4 categories are replaced by some integer values like

```
01 ONE FAMILY DWELLINGS instances are replaced by 0
10 COOPS - ELEVATOR APARTMENTS  instances are replaced by 1
02 TWO FAMILY DWELLINGS instances are replaced by 2
13 CONDOS - ELEVATOR APARTMENTS instances are replaced by 3
all the other instances are replaced by integer 4
```

So next time when I run the command it should output something like this:

```
> dataset["BUILDING CLASS CATEGORY"].value_counts()
0     12686
1     11518
2      9844
3      7965
4      6565   #sum of all the other instances
```

I have tried using LabelEncoder but my method is getting too long, so if there is an efficient way to do this, please do tell me.

Comment: why do you want to label them.. ?

Answer (score 0):

Let's just call your series like this for short:

```
building_cat = dataset["BUILDING CLASS CATEGORY"]
```

This is what you already did:

```
vc = building_cat.value_counts()
```

Now get list of top 4:

```
top4 = vc[:4].index.tolist()
```

And map it to your df:

```
building_cat  = building_cat.map(lambda x: top4.index(x) if x in top4 else 4)
```

I didn't download the dataset, if it doesn't work I'll try locally.

You can change type if needed:

```
building_cat  = building_cat.astype("category")
```